# Writing a Set in Terms of a Sequence of Sets

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Take a metric space $(M, d)$ and define a sequence $a_n$ on the metric space.
Define $$S=\{y \in M: \forall \epsilon >0 [a_n \in B_\epsilon(y)\space \text{infinitely often}]\}$$

My books says that this set can be written in terms of the sequence of sets $G_N$ where $G_N$ is the closure of the set $\{s_n: n \geq N\}$

My understanding of this would be that it would be $S={\bigcap} _N \bigcup _{n\geq N} G_N$

However, I have been taught this as a definition, and it is not clear to me what the sequence of sets would be. Likewise, if I defined  $$T=\{y \in M: \forall \epsilon >0 [a_n \in B_\epsilon(y)\space \text{almost always}]\}$$ I think that the correct answer would be $T={\bigcup} _N \bigcap _{n\geq N} G_N$

Answer (score 0):

I guess that $s_n$ if the same as $a_n$.

Put $S’=\bigcap_{N\in\Bbb N} G_N$. I claim that $S’=S$. Indeed, let $y\in S’$ and $\epsilon>0$ be an arbitrary number.  Then $B_\epsilon(y)$ is an open neighborhood of the point $y$, so it intersects each $G_N$. This is possible iff $a_n \in B_\epsilon(y)$ is infinitely often. That is, $y\in S$.  Conversely, if $y\in M$ and for each $\epsilon>0$ we have $a_n \in B_\epsilon(y)$ infinitely often then $y\in G_N$ for each $N$, so $y\in S’$.

I understood “almost always” as for all but finitely many $n$. If $y$ is any point from $T$, then $y$ is a limit of the sequence $\{a_n\}$. Since a sequence in a metric space can have at most one limit, we have $T=\{a\}$, if the sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to a point $a\in M$, and $T=\varnothing$, otherwise. 
If the sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to a point $a\in M$ then it is easy to check that $T=\{a\}=\bigcap_{N\in\Bbb N} G_N=S$. But if the sequence $\{a_n\}$ does not converge 
then we have a problem.  For instance, let $A$ be any separable subset of $M$ without isolated points and $\{a_n\}$ be the enumeration of a countable dense subset of $A$. Then $G_N=\overline{A}$ for each $N$. An other example: let $\{b_n\}$ be a convergent sequence of $M$ and $\{c_n\}$ be a sequence such that $d(c_m, c_n)\ge 1$ provided $m\ne n$ (for instance, we can put as $(M,d)$ the real line endowed with the usual metric $d$, $b_n=1/n$, and $c_n=n$ for each $n$). Now for each $n$ put $a_{2n}=b_n$ and $a_{2n+1}=c_n$. Then the sequence $\{a_n\}$ does not converge, but $\bigcap_{N\in\Bbb N} G_N=\{a\}\ne T$. Thus I do  not see a natural way to express $T$ in terms of $G_N$.